# Fetch twitter data in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, twitter, twitter4j

Please guide me on how to actually load twitter data in Apache hadoop and analyse it. I have heard it is done by using twitter API keys, but can anybody help figure out the steps

Comment: This doesn't sound like a job for Hadoop. You might be better off inserting the results of your Twitter calls into a database or files.

Comment: I would like to fetch a set of tweets for a keyword from twitter, and run jobs in the received data.It would be good if the data is fetched to a file/directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this github project for analyzing tweets in hadoop.

https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example

This page also includes how to setup flume, hive & oozie.

Installing hadoop, flume, oozie, hive: http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/CDH4-Installation-Guide.html